# Open PHP project with databases in NetBeans and configure it

Tags: php, netbeans, phpmyadmin, xdebug

Actually I want to contribute to PhpMyAdmin. I forked the code from github. It's currently in XAMPP.

In NetBeans, I clicked on `New Project -> PHP -> With existing sources` and selected the PhpMyAdmin folder in XAMPP directory.

When I click on Run, nothing happens. When I click on Debug, it shows "Waiting for connection (netbeans-xdebug)" forever, it doesn't proceed.

Are there any other steps to follow in addition to just making a new project with existing sources?

The PHP version in XAMPP is 5.6.30 as mentioned in PHPinfo.

Comment: Open your project in browser( firefox, chrome etc ) with http://localhost/your_project

Comment: I also want to debug it. Not Only Run it.